# Boostrap - Grid donde la imagen debería ocupar el 100% de su celda

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Tengo esta estructura con boostrap 4, donde quiero hacer un grid dividido en 3 partes tal como asi, el problema lo tengo en la primera parte donde muestro una imagen , este trozo de código

```
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
         <img width="100%" id="imagen-principal" src="<?php echo asset('images/coches/pruebas1.jpg'); ?>">
     </div>
```

Este trozo de código si le pongo el "width al 100%" la imagen no ocupa el 100% de esa parte del row, en cambio si se lo quito como la imagen es de 600x600px ocupa casi toda la pantalla.

Aquí todo el código entero.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px">

            <div class="row" style="border: 1px dotted black;margin-left: 0px">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img width="100%" id="imagen-principal" src="<?php echo asset('images/coches/pruebas1.jpg'); ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    Características adicionales
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="background: #FCF0EE;">
                    <b>Autor</b> : Pruebas
                    <b>Año de la prueba</b> : 2021
                    <i class="far fa-envelope"> </i> <a href="#">Enviar por email</a> <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-print"> </i>  <a href="#">Imprimir ficha</a> <br>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He probado tu código con una imagen de 600x600 y ocupa perfectamente la celda en la que está (se muestra con un tamaño 442x442px). Si cambio el tamaño de la celda la imagen se adapta. (Bootstrap 5)

Comment: si le añades la propiedad display block a la imagen, sigue sin ocupar el 100%?

Comment: Puedes probar con la propiedad css object-fit: cover en una clase aplicada la imagen.

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado con la opción de "display block" a la imagen....gracias